# How to replace two different strings in iPhone programming

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am reading CSV file in my application.

I want to replace two different strings and print as one line. for example:

```
string1#$string2#$string3####string4
```

I want to replace `#$` with `,` and  `####` with `\n`

and want to show the result on a `UILabel.`

Comment: you can try this..  NSString *completeString = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#$ "withString:@"\n"];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` method, like this:

```
NSString *orig = "string1#$string2#$string3####string4";
NSString *res = [orig stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#$" withString:@" "];
res = [res stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"####" withString:@"\n"];
```

Note that the original string does not get changed: instead, a new instance is produced with the replacements that you requested.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
String = [String stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#$" withString:@","];
String = [String stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"####" withString:@"\n"];
```

And then

```
yourLabel.text=String;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSString *string = @"####abc#$de";
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"####" withString:@"\n"];
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#$" withString:@","];
```

Hope it helps you